# Variable input error in Postfix Expression Calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

This postfix calculator works with an implemented stack, it works fine for normal postfix expressions such as '2 5 +', but there seems to be an issue in variable handling. When i run it, it returns this error:
Output:

7
27

```
   index.js:44
                throw new Error(`Invalid token encountered: ${token}`);
                ^

    Error: Invalid token encountered: A
        at PostfixCalculator.evaluate (index.js:44:19)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/runtime/javascript/3zxrd96tq_3zxykq39r/index.js:78:24)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
        at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I have posted the code below, please let me know what i have done wrong and how i can improve and fix it, i am a beginner so any advice will be appreciated thanks.

```
class PostfixCalculator {
  constructor() {
    // Initialize an empty stack to hold operands and an empty symbol table for variables
    this.stack = [];
    this.symbolTable = {};
  }

  // Method to evaluate postfix expressions
  evaluate(expression) {
    // Split the expression into tokens (operands, operators, or variables) using spaces
    const tokens = expression.split(' ');

    // Iterate through each token in the expression
    for (let token of tokens) {
      if (!isNaN(token)) {
        // If the token is a number, push it onto the stack as an operand
        this.stack.push(parseFloat(token)); // Push operands to the stack
      } else if (token in this.symbolTable) {
        // If the token is a known variable, push its corresponding value onto the stack
        this.stack.push(this.symbolTable[token]); // Push variable values to the stack
      } else {
        // If the token is an operator (+, -, *, /) or '=', perform the corresponding operation
        switch (token) {
          case '+':
            this.performOperation((a, b) => a + b); // Addition operation
            break;
          case '-':
            this.performOperation((a, b) => a - b); // Subtraction operation
            break;
          case '*':
            this.performOperation((a, b) => a * b); // Multiplication operation
            break;
          case '/':
            this.performOperation((a, b) => a / b); // Division operation
            break;
          case '=':
            // Perform variable assignment by popping value and variable name from the stack
            const value = this.stack.pop();
            const variable = this.stack.pop();
            this.symbolTable[variable] = value; // Store variable value in the symbol table
            break;
          default:
            // Throw an error for an invalid token encountered
            throw new Error(`Invalid token encountered: ${token}`);
        }
      }
    }

    // Check if the stack contains only one element after evaluation
    if (this.stack.length !== 1) {
      throw new Error('Invalid expression');
    }

    // Return the final result by popping the last element from the stack
    return this.stack.pop(); // Result will be the only element in the stack
  }

  // Method to perform arithmetic operations on operands
  performOperation(operation) {
    // Pop the last two operands from the stack
    const operand2 = this.stack.pop();
    const operand1 = this.stack.pop();
    // Perform the specified operation on the operands
    const result = operation(operand1, operand2);
    // Push the result back onto the stack
    this.stack.push(result);
  }
}

// Example usage:
const calculator = new PostfixCalculator();

// Evaluate postfix expressions
console.log(calculator.evaluate('3 4 +')); // Output: 7
console.log(calculator.evaluate('3 4 5 + *')); // Output: 27

// Handle variable assignments
console.log(calculator.evaluate('A 2 =')); // Setting variable A to 2
console.log(calculator.evaluate('B 3 =')); // Setting variable B to 3
console.log(calculator.evaluate('A B *')); // Output: 6 (Multiplication of variables A and B)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that is thrown is the error that has been placed to be thrown when the program has run out of options and doesn't recognise a token. In this case, you split up all of the expression "A 2 =" wherever there are spaces, so you first get 'A'. Your if statements try to check if this 'A' is a number, if it is a variable that ALREADY exists and finally if it is one of the mathematical signs. But it never accounts for the possibility that 'A' is a new variable. In that case you shouldn't throw an error, but rather save the name of this variable together with its value into your hash table, like so `this.symbolTable[token] = ...`.

Comment: There are a lot of things to take into account when making such an open calculator. Because I said that if the token is none of the options that are being checked then it must be a new variable and we should assign for it a value. However, in this case of a new variable you should also make sure to check that the input is in fact aimed at variable declaration because if you have sth like `A B *` and both A and B are new variables then you should throw an error or an alert to the user that the variables do not exist or sth similar depending on how you want to handle that case.

Comment: Also sth else that I picked up is that the expression "3 4 5 + *" returns 27. At first when I saw it I interpreted it as 3+4*5 = 23 but the calculator interpreted it as 3*(4+5) = 27. Maybe you did in fact aim it to work like that but I am just pointing it out just in case.